# Close and open div with same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open and close my menu with same button. here is my code.

```
<script>
$('#open-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mySidenav").css("width" , "250px");
  $("#l_m").css({"marginLeft": "250px", "position" : "absolute", "width" : "100%"});
  // $(this).attr('id','close-menu');
});

$('#close-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mySidenav").css("width" , "0");
  $("#l_m").css("marginLeft" , "0");
});
</script>
```

Check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uyjogg5e/10/

(I tried to add the line that is commented but when I click on it, nothing happens)

Comment: Why ask the same question again, and specially when it has been answered already with working example. https://jsfiddle.net/uyjogg5e/11/

Comment: Please google before posting questions on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the css property in a class:

```
.side-nav-show{
   width : 250px;
}
.l_m-show{
   marginLeft:250px;
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
}
```

and then toggle the classes on click of element:

```
$('#open-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mySidenav").toggleClass('side-nav-show');
  $("#l_m").toggleClass('l_m-show');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vmnrfhon/)**

Comment: correct way....

Comment: May i ask, why answer it when it has already been answered in the question the OP made yesterday?

Comment: I guess he tried to show him how it should work with the provided code.

Comment: I wasn't knowing its asked previously

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 0;
$('#open-menu').click(function() {
    if(a % 2 == 0){
       $("#mySidenav").css("width" , "250px");
       $("#l_m").css({"marginLeft": "250px", "position": "absolute", "width" : "100%"});
    }
    else{
       $("#mySidenav").css("width" , "0");
       $("#l_m").css("marginLeft" , "0");
    }
    a++;
});
```